# Redirect index.php request to http://localhost/website/ using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not so familiar with configuring my .htaccess yet so please help me out.

I have a link that goes to the index.php but I don't want index.php to appear in my url

```
eg. 
http://localhost/website/index.php
```

I want it to be redirected to the root folder which is

```
http://localhost/website/
```

So i tried searching for answers and this is what I got so far.

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now when I try to click home in my local website, instead of redirecting me to

```
http://localhost/website
```

it is being redirected to this -

```
http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/localhost/website/
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Nope. Not a framework.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this one

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes I made with my .htaccess does not take effect as soon as I refresh the page. Took me some time to clear my cache to see the effect. I tried different approaches to my question:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /?(.*)/index\.php
#RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The lines with # didn't solve my problem maybe its because of cache not being cleared, but anyways
this line below solved my problem but took me 5 times to clear my cache before I actually saw the result.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I got it from [htaccess generator](http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php)