# Redirect htaccess localhost to IP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working on a wordpress website using WAMP locally, I've got the site working fine on another local computer, however images aren't showing they're simply appearing as localhost/wp-content/etcetc instead of 10.0.1.2/wp-content/etcetc

CSS and everything else loads fine. Obviously the images load fine on the host computer, however I'm looking to setup so can work from LAN based machines too.

I figure htaccess would be a simple(ish) fix, if I at all knew what I was doing.

Basically could anyone point me in the direction of a htaccess code to directed localhost to 10.0.1.2 please?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you just said; can you explain in detail; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778687/redirect-index-php-request-to-http-localhost-website-using-htaccess

Comment: belthazorNv

I'm running wamp, working on a wordpress site, im trying to access said site and the backend of it from another computer on my LAN network. All of the website loads fine (loading under 10.0.1.2) however images still try and pull from 'localhost'.. the local host isnt the computer im trying to work from, thus images dont load. I'm trying to find a fix to solve that, I figured redirected anything that's localhost to that IP would solve the issue. Make any more sense? I'm trying to redirect AWAY from localhost to an IP, not folder to folder.

Comment: set site url in general settings http://10.0.1.2/yourwordpress also in db change localhost to ip and access your local network from this ip. Also need wamp online

Comment: Try as Rakesh told you Josh.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking is not the correct one - you do not want to change `localhost` to point to a specific private IP address or you will have issues with an unknown number of other things.

To properly correct the issue you will need to go through the process of [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) - updating the URLs in the `options`, `postmeta`, and `posts` tables. This can also be achieved by exporting the contents of your site to an XML file, doing a search and replace on this text document (change `localhost` to `10.0.1.2` or whatever host name you want), and then re-uploading it. You will need to update the `site_url` and `wp_home` values as well.

Comment: Hi, I've already set the site_url and wp_home values (both in general settings and checked database), I've downloaded the XML file just, yes it did have some localhosts still in it, I've changed them and reuploaded however it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Solved by manually editing all database entries that myphpadmin search produced. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to Dashboard > Settings > General
2. In the 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' labeled text boxes replace the word 'localhost' with your IP address.
3. Save changes.

This solves your problem.

Comment: No it doesn't, I had already done that long before posting this.